# Change a body Field name in a Post in Spray

Tags: scala, spray-json

I'm thinking to replace a field called "type" in a JSON in a POST with somethig like this

```
def rawJson = extract { _.request.entity.asString}
post {
    rawJson { json => 
       val new json = println(json.replace("\"type\":", "\"eventType\":"))}
}
```

And now, with this new JSON I want to reinject the POST to trate it like a new call. 
I know "redirect" but I don't see the way to use it in this case.

Thanks!

Comment: Any particular reason for making a new call rather than just transforming the request?

Comment: You are right. I've transform the request instead and Everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question. I hope someone else can found it useful:
I've change the post on-the-fly. My problem was that I was using: `entity(as[Event])` and I was unable to transform it. But deserializing it like a JObject I have the control of the fields. It's a very powerful tool.

```
    post {
      entity(as[JObject]) {
        eventO =>
          val nevent: json4s.JValue = eventO.mapField(x => if (x._1=="type") ("eventType",x._2) else (x._1,x._2))
          val event = nevent.extract[Event]
          handlePerRequest {
            RouteMessageToCluster(event)
          }
      }
    }
```